# replace the header line of several sequences in a fasta file and replace them with the species names stored in a list (.txt)

Tags: bash, awk, sequence, rename, spp

I have a fasta file with several sequences, but the first line of all the sequences start with the same string (ABI) and I want to change and replace it with the names of the species stored in a different text file.

My fasta file looks like

```
>ABI
AGCTAGTCCCGGGTTTATCGGCTATAC
>ABI
ACCCCTTGACTGACATGGTACGATGAC
>ABI
ATTTCGACTGGTGTCGATAGGCAGCAT
>ABI
ACGTGGCTGACATGTATGTAGCGATGA
```

The list of spp looks like this:

```
Alsophila cuspidata
Bunchosia argentea
Miconia cf.gracilis
Meliosma frondosa
```

How I can change those ABI headers of my sequences and replace them with the name of my species using that exact order.

Required output:

```
>Alsophila cuspidata
AGCTAGTCCCGGGTTTATCGGCTATAC
>Bunchosia argentea
ACCCCTTGACTGACATGGTACGATGAC
>Miconia cf.gracilis
ATTTCGACTGGTGTCGATAGGCAGCAT
>Meliosma frondosa
ACGTGGCTGACATGTATGTAGCGATGA
```

I was using something like:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
($2 in a) && /^>/{
  print ">"a[$2]
  next
}
1
' spp_list.txt FS="[> ]"  all_spp.fasta
```

This is not working, could someone guide me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello, not a dev so don't be rude.

Hope this will help you:

I create a file fasta.txt that contains:

```
>ABI
AGCTAGTCCCGGGTTTATCGGCTATAC
>ABI
ACCCCTTGACTGACATGGTACGATGAC
>ABI
ATTTCGACTGGTGTCGATAGGCAGCAT
>ABI
ACGTGGCTGACATGTATGTAGCGATGA
```

I also created a file spplist.txt that contains:

```
Alsophila cuspidata
Bunchosia argentea
Miconia cf.gracilis
Meliosma frondosa
```

I then created a python script named fasta.py, here it is:

```
#!/bin/python3

#import re library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
#import sys library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html
import re,sys

#saving the reference of the standard output into "original_stdout"
original_stdout = sys.stdout


with open("spplist.txt", "r") as spplist:
    x = spplist.readlines()
    with open("fasta.txt", "r") as fasta:
        output_file = open("output.txt", "w")
        #redirecting standard output to output_file
        sys.stdout = output_file

        for line in fasta:
            if re.match(r">ABI", line):
                print(x[0].rstrip())
                del x[0]
            else:
                print(line.rstrip())

        #restoring the native standard output
        sys.stdout = original_stdout

#Notify the user at the end of the work
print("job done")
```

(these three file need to be in the same directory if you want the script to work as it is)

Here is my directoy tree:

```
❯ tree
.
├── fasta.py
├── fasta.txt
└── spplist.txt
```

To execute the script, open a shell, cd in the directory and type:

```
❯ python3 fasta.py
job done
```

You will see a new file named output.txt in the directory:

```
❯ tree
.
├── fasta.py
├── fasta.txt
├── output.txt
└── spplist.txt
```

and here is its content:

```
Alsophila cuspidata
AGCTAGTCCCGGGTTTATCGGCTATAC
Bunchosia argentea
ACCCCTTGACTGACATGGTACGATGAC
Miconia cf.gracilis
ATTTCGACTGGTGTCGATAGGCAGCAT
Meliosma frondosa
ACGTGGCTGACATGTATGTAGCGATGA
```

Hope this can help you out.
bguess.